# Why does the Newton-Raphson method work?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

Newton-Raphson method is used to find the roots/zero of real valued function.

I am not able to understand the correctness of the algorithm.

$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$

my question is why the equation guarantees that it will eventually find the root of function after multiple iterations.

Comment: see here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oE98W4A7Zio i hope this will help you

Comment: The equation does not guarantee this. It only does it for values of $x_0$ close enough to a root, assuming $f$ is reasonably nice.

Comment: Some conditions are required for the method to converges, nonetheless, the idea comes from:
$$f(x)=f(x_0)+f'(x)(x-x_0)+o(x-x_0).$$
Instead of seeking the zeroes of a non-linear function, one uses the linear estimate of this function, namely its tangent linear map.

Comment: It doesn't guarantee, but it usually does work.  The premise is that all continuous functions are approximately linear at some level.  So we use a linear approximation, find the zero for that line and repeat.

Comment: "[...] guarantees  [...]" It doesn't. $f$ might not even have a root.

Comment: The formula can be deduced fast remembering that it finds the root in one iteration if the function is a straight line. 
$f'(x_n)=\dfrac{f(x_{n+1})-f(x_n)}{x_{n+1}-x_{n}}$ with 
$f(x_{n+1})=0$

Comment: In general, the method does not find roots, especially not in a finite number of steps. In the case that the method works, it finds successively better approximations of a root.

Answer (score 1):

Here's A DIY approach. Grab a pencil and paper

(0) Draw a curve intersecting the $x$-axis at some point.

(1) Mark a point $x_o$ on the $x$-axis at some initial guess for $x$. Set $k=0$

(2) Draw a vertical line from $x_k$ on the $x$-axis till it meets the curve.

(3) From this point on the curve draw a tangent to the curve, till it intersects the $x$-axis.

(4) Set $k=k+1$ and Call this new point on the $x$-axis, $x_k$ (This is your updated value) .

Repeat Steps (2) -- (4) till convergence

It is **ONLY** guaranteed to work if $f(x)$ has a continuous first derivative and no saddle point (zero slope with $f(x)\ne 0$) between your initial guess and the root closest to the initial guess, if it exists.